# How do i create an undetermined amount of variables in a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php.

I need a while loop to run as long as a specific query value returned by mysql is greater than 0.

For each iteration of the loop i need to place the query value in a different variable.

The problem is depending on where in the table the loop starts from, it will run a variable amount of times.

How do I get the loop to declare a new unique variable for every iteration?

I tried:

```
$i = 0
while (condition)
{
    $array[i] = queryresult;
    i++;
}
```

But i think it literally took $array[i] as a variable, instead of assuming that "i" was another variable.

I'm sure that there's a simple answer that someone with more experience can tell me :)

Comment: If you're using `PDO` to fetch your table, why not doing `->fetchAll()` in your statement? We need more info about your manner of querying your table.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
$i = 0
while (condition)
{
    $array[$i] = queryresult;
    $i++;
}
```

so that PHP can interpret the $i as a variable. This way it should work.

Comment: ps. missing semi colon after lines $i = 0 & $i++.

Comment: Hmm, so that IS the way to do it? It wasnt working for me... (I know i forgot the $ a couple times in my post but i didnt do that in my code.) Ok well as long as i know that's the proper way im sure i made a simple mistake somewhere :). Thanks for confirmation!

Comment: Yes, that's how you can do it.
JonLBevan: Thanks, I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

forget `$i`. just do this:

```
$array = array();
while(condition) {
    $array[] = $query_result;
}
```

if you omit the array index it will append to the end.